# Find with range cells

Tags: vba, excel

do you have any clue on why the following code does not work?

```
begin=1    
Set FoundCell = ws.Range(Cells(begin,6),Cells(200000,6)).Find(What:=Content(i))
```

It says no Object found, if instead of `Cells(begin,6),Cells(200000,6)` I put `"F:F"` it does work. But I need to give dynamically the starting point of search (i.e. `begin`)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not define the "Parent" worksheet, then VBA assumes that the "Parent" worksheet is the `ActiveSheet`. Thus here:

```
ws.Range(Cells(begin,6),Cells(200000,6))
```

you have defined the "Parent" for `.Range()`, but for `Cells` it is not defined, thus it is considered to be the active one, which is obviously different than `ws`.

In general, make sure that you always define the worksheet that your `Cells` and `Ranges` should be located on. Like this:

```
With ws
    Set FoundCell = .Range(.Cells(begin,6),.Cells(200000,6)).Find(What:=Content(i))
End With
```